# How to query Oracle v$ tables using Groovy

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy

I'm trying to query the Oracle v$session table using Groovy (imported groovy.sql.SQL) like this:

```
sql.eachRow("""
Select
'Y' as runInd
from v$session
where upper(module) = ?
having count(*) > 1
""", [programName]) {row -> etc...}
```

But Groovy keeps telling me:  "Groovy:Apparent variable 'session' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class."

It apparently doesn't like the table called v$session.  I've tried many things, I'm not sure why I can't find out how to do this.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Tom

Comment: What are the many things you have tried? Do they include escaping it as `v\$session`, using ['slashy strings'](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString), or concatenating two partial strings?

Comment: Use three single quotes `'''` instead of double quotes `"""` to declare your multi line string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `"""` which marks it as a multi-line templated groovy string, try `'''` which shouldn't try to template things following a `$`:

```
sql.eachRow( '''Select
               |  'Y' as runInd
               |  from v$session
               |  where upper(module) = ?
               |  having count(*) > 1'''.stripMargin(), [programName]) { row ->
    etc...
}
```